# How can I debug a hang when debug-on-quit doesn't work?

Tags: debugging

I have a problem with haskell-mode where Emacs will hang every time I open up a Haskell file. Mashing Ctrl-g a few times will get the file opened.

So I would imagine setting `debug-on-quit` would allow me to debug the issue. But it doesn't. No debugger shows up. Likewise if I run this elisp code `(while 1)`. Emacs locks up, Ctrl-g will will break out of the hang, but no debugger.

I can sometimes bring up the debugger. Say if I run grep and then Ctrl-g whilst it is running, I will get a backtrace popping up.

So I'm not totally sure what is going on. Is there another way I should be debugging this hang with haskell-mode?

*GNU Emacs 26.2 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0, Carbon Version 158 AppKit 1561.6)*

Comment: In your `(while 1)` example, `C-g` does bring me the debugger as expected.

Comment: Ah interesting. It does bring up the debugger if I break in the *scratch* buffer, but not if I break in ielm.

Comment: Oh, I see, that's because ielm captures the quit signal via `(condition-case err ... (quit ...))`.

Comment: Most likely this is a font-lock problem. Try to disable `global-font-lock-mode` before opening the file.

Comment: @Lindydancer Ah, yes you are correct. That does stop the hanging! But I now have no syntax highlighting.. How did you find this out?

Comment: I've been writing font-lock packages and tools for 20+ years, and this is a typical and font-lock problem. You can run `font-lock-studio` (available from Melpa) to single-step the font lock rules to find out which is broken.

Comment: @Lindydancer so I've tracked down the problem. It isnt due to font-lock, but disabling font-lock did enable me to get a stack trace when it locked up as I was editing a file. If you want to put a proper answer recommending to disable global-font-lock to make debugging easier, I will accept it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Mongus Pong, thanks, but I think it would be more helpful to the community to post an answer where you describe the real problem. I'm just glad I could help.

Comment: @Lindydancer Ok, I will try. I don't 100% understand why, but I'll try and write down the how.

Answer (score 2):

So it seems that I was able to bypass the problem from occuring whilst opening the file by disabling global-font-lock-mode (`M-x global-font-lock-mode`). (Thanks to @Lindydancers advice.)

For reasons currently unknown to me, if Emacs hangs whilst opening the file, pressing Ctrl-G doesn't bring up the debugger.

This did at least allow me to open the file. While editing the file Emacs would occasionally hang, and this time pressing Ctrl-G did bring up the debugger which did allow me to locate where the problem was. There is something going on in the Lexer of haskell mode.

So although I don't fully understand why the debugger didn't open during file load, if you have a similar hang whilst opening the file, it is probably well worth disabling font-lock-mode which should get you a few steps further to debugging the actual issue.

Comment: I think the debugger is suppressed during redisplay, and redisplay might the one calling font-lock.

Answer (score 2):

Try sending Emacs the `SIGUSR2` signal, or whatever signal is specified by the Emacs variable `debug-on-event`. The easiest way to do this is probably to run `killall -SIGUSR2 emacs`.

Comment: If you can put Emacs into a responsive state, then `M-: (emacs-pid)` will tell you the process ID number to use: `kill -SIGUSR2 <pid>`

Comment: Failing that, I would personally always use `ps` to figure out which PID to use, as I invariably have more than one instance of Emacs running.

Comment: Also note that `debug-on-quit` is set when this signal is processed.  You can use `M-x toggle-debug-on-quit` to switch that off again.